# Bind residuals to input dataset with missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, regression

I am looking for a method to bind `lm` residuals to an input dataset. The method must add `NA` for missing residuals and the residuals should correspond to the proper row.

Sample data:

```
N <- 100 
Nrep <- 5 
X <- runif(N, 0, 10) 
Y <- 6 + 2*X + rnorm(N, 0, 1) 
X[ sample(which(Y < 15), Nrep) ] <- NA
df <- data.frame(X,Y)

residuals(lm(Y ~ X,data=df,na.action=na.omit))
```

Residuals should be bound to df.

Comment: Similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6882709/684229) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"[<-"(df, !is.na(df$X), "res", residuals(lm(Y ~ X,data=df,na.action=na.omit)))
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain this? What is `"[<-"`?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen The function `"[<-"(x1, x2, x3, x4)` is similar to `x1[x2, x3] <- x4` but leaves `x1` unchanged and returns a new object.

Answer (score 10):

Simply change the `na.action` to `na.exclude`:

```
residuals(lm(Y ~ X, data = df, na.action = na.exclude))
```

`na.omit` and `na.exclude` both do casewise deletion with respect to both predictors and criterions. They only differ in that extractor functions like `residuals()` or `fitted()` will pad their output with NAs for the omitted cases with `na.exclude`, thus having an output of the same length as the input variables.

(this is the best solution found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11028/5509))

Comment: This is the general solution you're looking for, the one that works with missings in any number of predictors or DV, with lm and lme4.

Answer (score 2):

Using merge, or join.

```
N <- 100 
Nrep <- 5 
X <- runif(N, 0, 10) 
Y <- 6 + 2*X + rnorm(N, 0, 1) 
X[ sample(which(Y < 15), Nrep) ] <- NA
df <- data.frame(X,Y)

df$id <- rownames(df)

res <- residuals(lm(Y ~ X,data=df,na.action=na.omit))
tmp <- data.frame(res=res)
tmp$id <- names(res)

merge(df,tmp,by="id",sort=FALSE,all.x=TRUE)
```

If you need to maintain the order. Use join() from the plyr package:

```
library(plyr) 
join(df,tmp)
```

Comment: couldn't this code be simplified by [merging by row names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7739757/684229)?

Comment: There is much much simpler solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This maybe could be solution, but, first, you do not need c() in data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(X,Y)
df$Res[!is.na(X)]<-residuals(lm(Y ~ X,data=df,na.action=na.omit))
```

Comment: This duplicates residuals. Rather than appending NA

Comment: I've removed the `c()` in `data.frame`

Comment: What if Y is NA? What if another predictor variables is NA? Not very robust to this, thus probably not a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
N <- 100 
Nrep <- 5 
X <- runif(N, 0, 10) 
Y <- 6 + 2*X + rnorm(N, 0, 1) 
X[ sample(which(Y < 15), Nrep) ] <- NA
df <- data.frame(X,Y)

R.all=as.numeric(rep(NA,length(X)))  # numeric vector with missing values
res=residuals(lm(Y ~ X,data=df,na.action=na.omit))  
i=as.numeric(names(res)) # vector locations of non-missing residuals
R.all[i]=res;R.all     # assign residuals to their correct positions.
```