# merge residuals to data with missing obs na.exclude not working

Tags: r, na, lm

I have the following command to estimate the residuals from a linear regression and then merge it to the data. The data has missing values in the variable of interest but as I'm doing it on many variable I would like the residuals of my regression for NA values to just be NA.

I've seen on [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672690/bind-residuals-to-input-dataset-with-missing-values) that na.action=na.exclude should do the work just fine but it doesn't seems to do anything. Would you have an idea of why na.action is not working?

```r
d <- lm(log(br_prix) ~ sectoryear, data=test,na.action = na.exclude)

P1 <- as.data.frame(d$residuals)

P1 <- P1 %>% dplyr::rename(lnprice = "d$residuals")

test <- cbind(test,P1)
```

Comment: Minor note: `P1 <- as.data.frame(d$residuals); P1 <- P1 %>% dplyr::rename(lnprice = "d$residuals")` is a long way to write `P1 <- data.frame(lnprice = d$residuals)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the shorter command to rename and create a data frame! The predict() method however gives values to the observations with NA.

Answer (score 2):

As the `cbind()` requires vectors to be the same length, we expect throwing error when joining data with missing values and residuals. luckily, the residuals of `lm` object have `name attributes` which are the row names of `non-missing values` of original data `(test)`. Using the attributes we could join the residuals to the data, filling corresponding missing rows with `NA` in the residual column.
I created a simple data frame containing two missing values to indicate the solution:

```
x <- c(4, 7, 8, 6, 9, 9.8)
y <- c(5, 8, NA, 8.7, NA, 9.8)

test <- data.frame(x,y)
test
    x   y
1 4.0 5.0
2 7.0 8.0
3 8.0  NA
4 6.0 8.7
5 9.0  NA
6 9.8 9.8

d <- lm(y ~ x, data = test)
attributes(d$residuals)
$names
[1] "1" "2" "4" "6"
```

we can see that rows `3` and `5` are dropped from `residuals` as they are missing in the `test` data. Using the row indices, we can join the residuals to the data and giving an optional name to residuals column in the data (here I renames "`resid`"):

```
 test [attr(d$residuals , which = "name"), "resid"] <- d$residuals
 test
    x   y      resid
1 4.0 5.0 -0.8376430
2 7.0 8.0 -0.1013730
3 8.0  NA         NA
4 6.0 8.7  1.3532037
5 9.0  NA         NA
6 9.8 9.8 -0.4141876
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works very well! I love the nice description also! :)