# In R, how to add the fitted value column to the original dataframe?

Tags: r, regression

I have a multiple regression model.  I want to add the fitted values and residuals to the original `data.frame` as two new columns.  How can I achieve that?  My model in R is like this:

```
BD_lm <- lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, data=BD)
summary(BD)
```

I also got the fitted value

```
BD_fit<-fitted(BD_lm)
```

But I want to add this `BD_fit` values as a column to my original data `BD`. I don't know how. When I tried to call `BD_fit`, it just gave me a lot of numbers. I am running a large dataset, so it is hard to list all of them here.

Comment: See this Cross Validated post for useful information on handling predicted values when your regression uses a subset of your total data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Suppose:

```
fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)
```

Then try this:

```
cbind(BOD, resid = resid(fm), fitted = fitted(fm))
```

or this:

```
BOD$resid <- resid(fm)
BOD$fitted <- fitted(fm)
```

ADDED:

If you have `NA` values in `demand` then your fitted values and residuals will be of a different length than the number of rows of your data, meaning the above will not work.  In such a case use: `na.exclude` like this:

```
BOD$demand[3] <- NA # set up test data
fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD, na.action = na.exclude)
```

`na.exclude` will automatically pad the predictions and residuals with `NA` values so that they are of the same length as the original data. Now the previous lines should work.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but i got an error:"Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 355027, 53467" The 355027 is the row number of my original data, and the 53467, i'm not sure what is it. maybe the problem is my fitted values is not the same number as the original data? i'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @titi Do you have missing values in BD?  You won't get a prediction for any records with missing values, which will make your vector of fitted values shorter than your original data frame.

Comment: Yes, i figured out that it's because of the missing values. Now i got it. Thanks.

Comment: Have added some info on NA handling.

Comment: subtle point I was missing (h/t to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882709/how-do-i-deal-with-nas-in-residuals-in-a-regression-in-r) answer for setting me straight) is that `fm$residuals` will still not return any `NA` with `na.action = na.exclude`; rather, it's the `resid` function that recognizes & interprets this attribute of `fm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BD_fit<-data.frame(BD_fit)
BD$fit<-BD_fit[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Despite not knowing your case in detail, adding to a data frame is quite easy. You could jsut add a new column like so:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=1:10)
df$var2 <- 11:20
```

You only have to make sure that your additional data columns have the same length as the original ones. Otherwise, you won't be able to add them to your data frame.